# How to use method from a class to a GUI?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, data-structures

My GUIForm gets an error if I use a method from the other class I have. Can u guys also tell me if what I did is right? Some revisions is appreciated. Thank you! Here's my code:

***Books.java***

```
package exer_sec;

public class Books {

private String author;
private String title;
private int numOfPages;

private String[] arr_author;
private String[] arr_title;
private long[] arr_pages;

public Books(String[] author, String[] title, long[] numOfPages) {
    this.arr_author = author;
    this.arr_title = title;
    this.arr_pages = numOfPages;
}

public Books() {
    this.author = "JK Rowling";
    this.title = "Harry Potter";
    this.numOfPages = 223;
}

public String[] getAuthor() {
    return arr_author;
}

public void setAuthor(String[] author) {
    this.arr_author = author;
}

public String[] getTitle() {
    return arr_title;
}

public void setTitle(String[] title) {
    this.arr_title = title;
}

public long[] getNumOfPages() {
    return arr_pages;
}

public void setNumOfPages(long[] numOfPages) {
    this.arr_pages = numOfPages;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
return "Author = " + arr_author + "  | Title = " + arr_title + " | Pages = " +    arr_pages;
}

public void displayAuthors() {
    System.out.print("Authors: ");

    if (arr_author.length >= 1) {
        System.out.print(arr_author[0]);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < arr_author.length; i++)
        System.out.print(", " + arr_author[i] );
    System.out.println("");
    /*
    for (int i = 1; i < arr_author.length; i++)
        System.out.println(arr_author[i] );
    */
}

public void displayTitles() {
    System.out.print("Titles: ");

    if (arr_title.length >= 1) {
        System.out.print(arr_title[0]);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < arr_title.length; i++)
        System.out.print(", " + arr_title[i] );
    System.out.println("");
}

public void displayPages() {
    System.out.print("Pages: ");

    if (arr_pages.length >= 1) {
        System.out.print(arr_pages[0]);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < arr_pages.length; i++)
        System.out.print(", " + arr_pages[i] );
    System.out.println("");
}

public void display1() {
    displayAuthors();
    displayTitles();
    displayPages();
}

public void display2(Books[] x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(x[i]);
    }
}

}
```

***Main.java***

```
package exer_sec;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Books b1 = new Books();
    BubbleSort bub = new BubbleSort();

    String[] authors = {"James Dashner", "Veronica Roth", "Joanne Rowling",
                        "Suzanne Collins", "Rick Riordan"};
    String[] titles = {"Maze Runner", "Divergent", "Harry Potter",
                        "Hunger Games", "Percy Jackson"};
    long[] pages = {374, 487, 309, 391, 384};

    b1.setAuthor(authors);
    b1.setTitle(titles);
    b1.setNumOfPages(pages);

    System.out.print("OUTPUT \n");
    b1.display1();

    System.out.print("\nBUBBLE SORT \n");
    bub.sortString(authors);
    bub.sortString(titles);
    bub.sortNum(pages);
    b1.display1();

}

}
```

***BubbleSort.java***

```
package exer_sec;

public class BubbleSort extends Books {

public void sortString(String[] x) {
    int j;
    String temp;
    boolean flag = true;

    while (flag) {

        flag = false;

        for (j = 0; j < x.length - 1; j++) {
            if (x[j].compareTo(x[j + 1]) > 0) {
                temp = x[j];
                x[j] = x[j + 1];
                x[j + 1] = temp;
                flag = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void sortNum(long[] x) {
    int j;
    int temp;
    boolean flag = true;

    while (flag) {

        flag = false;
        for (j = 0; j < x.length - 1; j++) {
            if (x[j] > x[j + 1]) {
                temp = (int) x[j];
                x[j] = x[j + 1];
                x[j + 1] = temp;
                flag = true;
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

***Form.java***
the GUI. this is for the button that would perform the action but it wouldnt work T_T

```
package exer_sec;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Form extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Books b1 = new Books();

public Form() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    txtarea_beforesort = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    txtarea_aftersort = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextArea3 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 255));
    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0), 2));

    txtarea_beforesort.setColumns(20);
    txtarea_beforesort.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Monospaced", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
    txtarea_beforesort.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(txtarea_beforesort);

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Calibri", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setText("BEFORE SORTING...");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
            .addContainerGap())
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(135, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addGap(128, 128, 128))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 144, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGap(14, 14, 14))
    );

    jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 204, 204));
    jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0), 2));

    txtarea_aftersort.setColumns(20);
    txtarea_aftersort.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Monospaced", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
    txtarea_aftersort.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(txtarea_aftersort);

    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Calibri", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
    jLabel3.setText("AFTER SORTING...");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2)
            .addContainerGap())
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel3)
            .addGap(132, 132, 132))
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jLabel3)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 144, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Calibri", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
    jButton1.setText("Bubble Sort");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Calibri", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
    jButton2.setText("Selection Sort");

    jPanel3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 204));

    jTextArea3.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Monospaced", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
    jTextArea3.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane3.setViewportView(jTextArea3);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
    jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
    jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 231, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Calibri", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("PAGADUAN_exer_02");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 131, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addContainerGap())
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 20, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 121, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap(13, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    txtarea_beforesort.append(b1.display1());
    //txtarea_beforesort.setText(b1.display1());
}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Form().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea3;
private javax.swing.JTextArea txtarea_aftersort;
private javax.swing.JTextArea txtarea_beforesort;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: You are setting text with a method and that return type is void. That method should return a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your methods does not return anything, as the return type is `void`.

Change your methods to return as string;

```
public String sortString(String[] x) {
  int j;
  String temp;
  boolean flag = true;

  while (flag) {

      flag = false;

      for (j = 0; j < x.length - 1; j++) {
          if (x[j].compareTo(x[j + 1]) > 0) {
              temp = x[j];
              x[j] = x[j + 1];
              x[j + 1] = temp;
              flag = true;
          }
       }
    }
  return x; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

All four these methods should return a String instead of void and printing

```
public void display1() {  // 1
    displayAuthors();     // 2
    displayTitles();      // 3
    displayPages();       // 4
}
```

Example

```
public String display1() {

    return displayAuthors() + " " +  displayTitles() + " " + displayPages();

}

public String displayTitles() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Titles: ");

    if (arr_title.length >= 1) {
        sb.append(arr_title[0]);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < arr_title.length; i++)
        sb.append(", " + arr_title[i] );

    return sb.toString();
}

public String displayPages() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("Pages: ");

    if (arr_pages.length >= 1) {
        sb.append(arr_pages[0]);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < arr_pages.length; i++)
        sb.append(", " + arr_pages[i] );

    return sb.toString();
}

// and finally your displayAutors
```

Comment: See my edit. I changed the `display1()`. You may need to fix the formatting for how you want everything displayed. This is all just a template to work off of.

Comment: Tried the method displayTitles() in Main, it wont print anything.

Comment: Do you want it displayed in the text area or do you want it printed in the console?

Comment: You may also want to consider using      
    `txtarea_beforesort.append(someString);` This append strings instead of setting a new string.

Comment: in the text area. I tried the code u made, but when I try to run the GUI, i get an error.

Comment: Where is your gui code if this is a gui question. You only have you `Main` class which is a console program and not a gui program.

Comment: It's too long. But it's in Form.java